# How to add ellipses without fixing the width?

Tags: css

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mnpenner/txgh61y2/1/)

```css
.nowrap {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    /*width: 300px;*/
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.body {
    color: #777;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>From</th>
            <th>Subject/Body</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td><div class="nowrap"><span class="subject">Lorem Ipsum</span>
                <span class="body"> &ndash; Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt aliquet libero quis tempus. Vivamus id est purus. Nulla augue neque, vestibulum in vestibulum vitae, ornare vel nisi. Nullam non dolor tincidunt, mattis metus ac, feugiat sapien. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Integer mollis leo in tristique consectetur. Quisque non imperdiet neque. Nunc fermentum neque sit amet nulla interdum vestibulum. Sed ac tempus dolor.</span></div>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I keep the subject/body on one line, with ellipses at the end, without fixing the width of the container?

If ellipses aren't possible, how do I at least keep it from wrapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent the ellipsis overflows in the table cell, you could set the `<table>` as `table-layout:fixed` and `width:100%`, and set a fixed/percentage width on the first column.

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
th:first-child {
    width: 50px;
}
```

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: left;
}
th:first-child {
    width: 50px;
}
.ellipsis {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>From</th>
            <th>Subject/Body</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>
                <div class="ellipsis">
                    <span class="subject">Lorem Ipsum</span>
                    <span class="body"> &ndash; Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt aliquet libero quis tempus. Vivamus id est purus. Nulla augue neque, vestibulum in vestibulum vitae, ornare vel nisi. Nullam non dolor tincidunt, mattis metus ac, feugiat sapien. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Integer mollis leo in tristique consectetur. Quisque non imperdiet neque. Nunc fermentum neque sit amet nulla interdum vestibulum. Sed ac tempus dolor.</span>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ph98s1Lb/)**

For responsive table layouts, you could use two `<div>`s, and set them as `table` and `table-cell` respectively, plus the following styles.

```
.container {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
.ellipsis {
    display: table-cell;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: left;
}
.shrink {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.expand {
    width: 99.999%;
}
.container {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
.ellipsis {
    display: table-cell;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="shrink">From</th>
            <th class="expand">Subject/Body</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="shrink">Mark</td>
            <td class="expand">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="ellipsis">
                        <span class="subject">Lorem Ipsum</span>
                         <span class="body"> &ndash; Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt aliquet libero quis tempus. Vivamus id est purus. Nulla augue neque, vestibulum in vestibulum vitae, ornare vel nisi. Nullam non dolor tincidunt, mattis metus ac, feugiat sapien. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Integer mollis leo in tristique consectetur. Quisque non imperdiet neque. Nunc fermentum neque sit amet nulla interdum vestibulum. Sed ac tempus dolor.</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/o8j6k5m9/)**

Comment: Causes problems when combined with [my shrink/expand classes](http://jsfiddle.net/mnpenner/zgLux5q2/). Is there any way to get the other columns to be tight, without fixing their widths  like @sdcr suggests?

Comment: I was beginning to think this wasn't possible, but that works perfectly. Thank you!!